# Renewal reminders: repeat?

Tags: civimember, scheduled-reminders, repeating-events

When configuring reminders, there is a checkbox 'repeat'.

When configuring membership renewals, there is some debate on wether 'repeat' should be on or off and what that means.

https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-17880

https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-15461

I seem to read there, as of 4.6 the checkbox should *not* be checked. In fact, one user alerts that checking it started sending out loads of reminders that were already sent.

However, a client has random reminders not sending (about 25% already) and I want to make sure it's not the checkbox. It's *not* checked.

Is that OK?